# Broadleaf Commerce force OTP based login before choosing shipping address

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I would like to customize BLC login, so it forces user to login before adding shipping address and payments. We don't want guest checkout. Please suggest the best way to do this in site and API.

Also our login is based on mobile number and OTP(One time password) sent to mobile, please suggest how to customize the login part to accept mobile number and OTP in both Site and API.